# How to set the margin of a textview dynamiclly?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, margin

I will make a timetable for  my organizer app. My problem is:
- I have make a first row and make the second and every other row like this, but dynamically.
- I have a layout.xml for this, but the margin between the Views doesn´t work.

[image: Screenshot]

I want make the second row like the blue row/ first row. The yellow row should be dynamically (on runtime).

My sourcecode:

```
public class StundenplanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout tl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stundenplan);
        //Find the TableLayout defined in activity_stundenplan
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
        createRow();
    }

    public void createRow(){
        /* Create a new row to be added. */
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow_tabelle,null);

        String[] day = {"Zeit", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"};


        TextView[] spalte = new TextView[8];
        for(int i=0; i<=7; i++){
            TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view_tabelle, null);
            text.setText(day[i]);
            spalte[i] = text;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<=7; i++) {

            tr.addView(spalte[i]);
        }
        tl.addView(tr);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_stundenplan, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.item_einstellungen_stundenplan) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My layout xml for the dynamically textviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:background="#f0d000"
    android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop">

</TextView>
```

Edit: xml for tablerow_tabelle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1cf000">

</TableRow>
```

And the xml for the first Row (not dynamically):

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/mainactivity_horizontal_margin"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text0"
                android:text="@string/Zeit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text5"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text6"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text7"
                android:text="@string/Wochentag6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00f0c0"
                android:padding="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stundenplanactivity_marginTop"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: try adding it to your layout xml `R.layout.tablerow_tabelle`

Comment: I belive the question is: How can the following (dynamicly created) rows have the same margin as the first (hardcoded) row?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here this code works good to make different coloring for different rows. Well, it may be helps you.

In my code, i was used two rows. The first Table layout was Header row and second table layout is value rows. I was set background of header as background image and value layouts having background color.

**In XML Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridValue1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout         
            android:id="@+id/GridFrozenTable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:stretchColumns="*"

            />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"


            >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GridFrozenTable">

                <TableLayout  
                    android:id="@+id/GridContentTable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**In Java code :**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void PopulateMainTable(ActionCodeReport[] content) {

    TableRow HeaderRow = new TableRow(this);
    HeaderRow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2);

    TextView HeaderCell1 = new TextView(this);
    HeaderCell1.setText("Action code ");
    HeaderCell1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    HeaderCell1.setHeight(65);
    HeaderCell1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    HeaderCell1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lt); //Here i set background image for header
    HeaderRow.addView(HeaderCell1);


    TextView HeaderCell2 = new TextView(this);
    HeaderCell2.setText("NoOfAccnt");
    HeaderCell2.setHeight(65);
    HeaderCell2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lt);  //Same image
    HeaderCell2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    HeaderRow.addView(HeaderCell2);
    HeaderCell2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        TableRow contentRow = new TableRow(this);
        contentRow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2);


        int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        TextView Cell1 = new TextView(this);
        Cell1.setText(r.getAction_Code());
        Cell1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Cell1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        Cell1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);  //**Here change your background color as you need**
        contentRow.addView(Cell1);

        TextView Cell2 = new TextView(this);
        Cell2.setText(String.valueOf(r.getNoOfAccount()));
        Cell2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Cell2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        contentRow.addView(Cell2);


       contentTable.addView(contentRow);
    }
```

Surely, i may helps you!! 
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin using layout XML file.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
```

For changing some particular side margins use this code.

```
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
```

Comment: It doesn´t work for me. I have set the margin like that. I´ll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
TextView txtvew= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ForgotPasswordText);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0)
    txtvew.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Comment: My second row disappear.